# Visualizing QR factorization with drawmatrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I am using the [`drawmatrix`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/drawmatrix/drawmatrix.pdf) package and I would like to illustrate the following [picture](https://courses.seas.harvard.edu/courses/am205/fall13/AM205_unit_2_chapter_3.pdf#page=14)

[image]

This is my attempt

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{drawmatrix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}


A matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $m\geq n$, can be factorized
into $A=QR$ where $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ is orthogonal,
$R\equiv\begin{bmatrix}\widehat{R}\\0\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$,
$\widehat{R}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is upper triangular.

\[
    \drawmatrix[width=1.2, height=2]{A}=
    \drawmatrix[width=2, height=2, fill=yellow!10]{Q}\;
    \drawmatrix[width=1.2, height=1.2, upper, bbox style={fill=green!10}]{\widehat{R}}
    \drawmatrix[width=1.2, height=1]{0}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of drawing R-hat and 0 separately, you should just draw a single triangular matrix with an enlarged bounding box using `\drawmatrix[width=1.2, height=1.2, upper, bbox height=2,bbox style={fill=green!10}]{R}`

Comment: Thank you, It was what I wanted in a simple way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: main]

Could this be useful?  The code contains @Willie Wong 's suggestion.

**The code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{drawmatrix}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, tikzmark}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\xdefinecolor{B}{RGB}{0, 102, 221}
\begin{document}

\noindent
A matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $m\geq n$, can be factorized
into $A=QR$ where $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ is orthogonal,
$R = \begin{bmatrix}\widehat{R}\\0\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$
with $\widehat{R} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ upper triangular.

\drawmatrixset{%
  black!40, fill=B!30,
  bbox style={draw, black!40}
}
\[
  \drawmatrix[width=1.2, height=2]{A}
  = \drawmatrix[width=2, height=2]{Q}
  \;\tikzmark{tmp}\;
  \drawmatrix[width=1.2, height=1.2,
  upper, bbox height=2]{R}
  = \drawmatrix[width=1.2, height=2]{\widehat{Q}} \;
  \drawmatrix[width=1.2, height=1.2, upper]{\widehat{R}}.
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \path
    ($(pic cs:tmp) +(-1pt, 2pt)$)
    node[draw, dashed, left,
    minimum width=.9cm, minimum height=2.2cm] {};
    \path 
    ($(pic cs:tmp) +(1pt, -.12)$)
    node[draw, dashed, below right,
    minimum width=1.3cm, minimum height=.9cm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```